# how to give background color to textarea field in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

need give background color to My text area field in bootstrap
this is text area field

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
     <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="6"  placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this class.

```
textarea#exampleTextarea {
    background: gray;
}
```

Or you can use this as well.

```
#exampleTextarea {
    background: gray;
}
```

Comment: By add this property border: 0px; if you will see effect then first add this border: 5px solid black; and then remove 5px and set 0px so you will get idea.

Answer (score 1):

you can try it

```
textarea#exampleTextarea{ 
    background-color:gray !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one of this prepared classes https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/colors/#background-color like `.bg-warning` or `.bg-danger` etc:

```
<textarea class="bg-warning"></textarea>
```

or in your case it will be like

```
<textarea class="form-control bg-warning"...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
textarea.form-control {
color: #63AEEB
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ID

```
#email { 
  background-color: #E2E4E9 !important;
}
```